# Cannot set relations in relation view with phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, wamp

I set my tables to InnoDB and can enter the relation view. But I only can add constraints no relations. What causes the problem?

Server version: 5.7.14 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

phpMyAdmin Version: 4.6.4

WampServer Version: 3.0.6
[image]

Here a picture how I expect the view to be, the table "Internal relations" is missing:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: "I only can add constraints no relations. What causes the problem?"

A: I don't see any problematic behavior is being reported.

I see a description of the steps you've taken, and I'm guessing that the results of those steps aren't meeting your expectations.

If you could clarify what you expect, we might be able to help.

---

Briefly...

With InnoDB, a "*relationship*" between two tables can be expressed and enforced by creating a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint.

---

In relational database theory, a "*relation*" is a set of tuples. In an RDBMS, a "*relation*" is implemented as a `TABLE`.

---

If there was description of what you are attempting to achieve, and a more precise description of the problematic behavior you are observing, it would be possible to give some assistance.

---

**EDIT**

With InnoDB, we can use foreign keys defined in the database to represent the relationships between tables. Those are stored in InnoDB table definitions.

The PHPMyAdmin "internal relations" is used for MyISAM tables, which don't support foreign keys.

Verify that PHPMyAdmin is configured to store the "internal relations".  It stores the configuration in a table named `pma__relation`. The actual table name is specified in the configuration of PHPMyAdmin.

https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html

If that feature is enabled, there should be a line like this in the configuration file:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
```

(Consult the documentation for the version of PHPMyAdmin you are running.)

And verify that the `pma__relation` table exists in your database.

If everything looks to be configured correctly, then I would test the feature with a couple of test tables which use ENGINE=MYISAM, and see if it's working for those tables.

I don't know whether that feature is supposed to work for tables with storage engines other than MYISAM.  I don't know if it works with ENGINE=INNODB tables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I added a picture of how I expect the view to be.

Comment: @honiahaka10:  I don't know if that feature is supposed to work with INNODB tables, or just MYISAM tables. Check the PHPMyAdmin configuration and verify the name of the 'relation' table is specified, and that the table exists in your database. I've made an EDIT to my answer.

Comment: @spencer7593 your answer is excellent and very thorough. To add one thing, the internal relation feature should work with any table type (but in reality makes little sense for tables such as InnoDB where MySQL supports relationships). I agree that the most likely cause here is missing or incorrect configuration directive or database structure.

Comment: Thank you i got it now! Had to import `sql\create_tables.sql` first.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch what are the disadvantages of using the internal relation feature with InnoDB? Biggest benifit of that internal method is that I can link (and later see) foreign keys simply with a drop down menu within the GUI.

Comment: @honiahaka10 It's not that phpMyAdmin handles internal relationships differently with InnoDB tables, it's just that MySQL actually has relationships with that table type so it's better to use the native feature rather than the implementation done by phpMyAdmin. Using native InnoDB relationships will allow you to enforce data integrity and benefit from the relationships across all applications using the database; phpMyAdmin's internal relations are only useful when accessing the database through phpMyAdmin.

Comment: You can get the same graphical enhancements using InnoDB tables as you do with the internal tables; phpMyAdmin handles both sets of relations the same way. The big difference is when using other programs; only the InnoDB ones are visible to other applications.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch How can I get that graphical enhancements without using the Internal Relations?

Comment: It should just happen; if you have the same type of relationship defined using InnoDB tables as you would have using the internal relations, I would expect the interface to look the same when browsing or inserting data. Is that different from what you're experiencing? Note that, for instance in the Browse tab, you have to select "Display column for relations" to see the column referenced in the other table presented; IIRC this is a per-table setting.